# Symfony form is not submitted after data is sent using AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I sent a Symfony form through AJAX (jQuery).
However, even if data is clearly sent, the form is said by Symfony to be "not submitted" (no error actually, but some debug show that isSubmitted returns false).

**This is the code in my Controller**

```
public function emailrequestFormAction(Request $request)
{
    $result = new Result();
    $view = new View\EmailRequestView();
    $form = $this->createForm(new Type\formType(), $emailrequestview, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('ajax_form_emailrequest'),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Account/Form:formemailrequest.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

**This is the code in my formType**

```
class formType extends AbstractType {
public function getName()
{
    return 'formType';
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Name', 'text')
        ->add('Email', 'email')
        ->add('SendRequest', 'submit', array('label' => 'Invite me'))
        ->getForm();
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Bundle\AppBundle\Form\View\EmailRequestView',
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}}
```

**And this is my EmailRequestView.php**

```
class EmailRequestSignUpView {
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Name should not be blank")
 */
protected $Name;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Email should not be blank")
 */
protected $Email;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName(){ return $this->Name; }

/**
 * @param mixed $Name
 */
public function setName(String $Name){ $this->Name = $Name; }

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmail(){ return $this->Email; }

/**
 * @param mixed $Email
 */
public function setEmail(String $Email){ $this->Email = $Email; } }
```

Now for use Ajax Call function I insert a call on submit in my code on html page, this is the js Code:

```
function formSubmitAjaxForm(form, e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(form);
var formType = $this.attr("method");
var formUrl = $this.attr("action");
var formData = $this.serialize();

$.ajax({type: formType, url: formUrl, data: formData})
    .done(function (data) {
        var Result = data;
        try {
            // some code
        }
        catch (err) {
            // some code
        }
        finally {
            // some code
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // some code
    }); }
```

The Ajax call a ajax_emailrequestFormAction function on my Controller.

```
public function ajax_emailrequestFormAction(Request $request)
{
    $result = new Result();
    $emailrequestview = new View\EmailRequestView();
    $form = $this->createForm(new Type\EmailRequestType(), $emailrequestview, array('method' => 'POST'));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $data = $form->getData();

    /* Check if Method is POST */
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') == false) {
        $result->setSuccessful(false);
        $result->setMessage('You can access use Post Method!');
        return $result->ResponseJsonResult(400);
    }

    /* Check if Form is Submitted */
    if ($form->isSubmitted() === false) {
        $result->setSuccessful(false);
        $result->setMessage('Form not submitted.');
        return $result->ResponseJsonResult(200);
    }

    /* Check if Form is Valid */
    if ($form->isValid() === false) {
        $result->setSuccessful($form->isValid());
        $result->setMessage('Form is not valid.');
        return $result->ResponseJsonResult(200);
    }


    /* DataBase Operation */

    $result->setContext(', Name: ' . $form->get('Name')->getData() . ', Email: ' . $form->get('Email')->getData());
    $result->setMessage('Request send Successfully.');
    return $result->ResponseJsonResult(200);
}
```

*
The Result is: Successful: false and Message: Form is not valid.Details: ERROR: Name should not be blank. ERROR: Email should not be blank
*

Now i try to code this function:

```
$form->submit($request);

$form->handleRequest($request);

$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

but I not found a right method for get a value of my form just submitted.

Someone can i help me? (Note: Symfony version is 2.7 )

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED:**

All my code is right. The problem was during the submit ajax call, because i used jQuery v 2.xx.
The right solution is replace that version to jQuery v 1.xx

Thank for all, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Always take care of matching of the actions/methods:

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlSave,
        method: "post",
        data: elData,           
        dataType: 'json'
    })
```

Controller Action

```
/**
 * Process Ajax Request
 * @Route("/update", name="update_item")
 * @Method("post")
 */
public function ajaxItemUpdateItem(Request $request,){
```

And formType

```
$form=$this->container->get('form.factory')->create(
            new FormType(), $item, array(
                'action' =>  $this->container->get('router')->generate('label_editor_update_item'),
                'method' => 'post'
            )
    );
```